# ant cannot identify my jar files at all

Tags: java, ant, jar, compiler-errors

I have my jar files in Assignment2\lib folder and my build file is in Assignment2. The name of the jar file is Assignment1.jar The following is how I tried to compile my Assignment2 from build file through ant.

```
<project name="Assignment1" default="run" basedir=".">
    <property name="classes" value="classes" />
    <path id="project.class.path">
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}/"/>
        <pathelement path="${additional.path}"/>
    </path>
    <path id="lib.jars">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>
......
<target name="compile" description="compaling java files with Assignment2">
        <mkdir dir="build"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build" debug="on" failonerror="true">
            <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
            <classpath refid="lib.jars"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
<Project/>
```

I am getting compile errors. I'm using windows. Is that the problem? Is there any way to compile?

Comment: `lib.jars` path seems ok. I use the same structure in windows with no problems. From which path you execute ant? Take in account that basepath is `.`, so you should run from `Assignment2/`. Also check that in `lib/` are all requiered jars.

Answer (score 0):

Well,Everything looks good to me but, you can try the following to validate the same,

1. Check if the lib folder has all the necessary library jars required to compile you application
2. You can try assigning the relative path of the lib folder to a property and refer it in the classpath eg: Property lib value=".\Lib"
3. Try the following before you call the compile target to see the list of jars being included in the classpath

`<pathconvert property="libjars" refid="lib.jars"/>`

`<echo>libjars is ${classpathProp}</echo>`

Answer (score 0):

hey guys thanx for the answers actually i found probelm. i was trying to use a jar file created by netbeans files. Apparently netbeans jar files can be used only by netbeans. at the end i made a new jar file of Assingment1 and used it. now everything is fine. Thanx again for the answers.